# Finding number of seating arrangements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is the question I got in Purdue University's Probability course [available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0-NDtsQczo&list=PLNAxrEh0NNf428tm3dhwcbVdviEWpoj6S):

[image]

I don't understand they wrote *24 possible outcomes* . Outcomes are just 5:  5 people in 5 seats. Mathematically, 24 is the permutation than an outcome or it is total number of events. What I am not getting here ?

Comment: Draw diagrams of possible seating arrangements.  You should have no problem finding more than five such diagrams.  If you're careful, you will find all 24 possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Number of sitting configurations of $n$ people around a circular table is $(n-1)!$. The way to calculate this is to first have one arbitrary person seated and treat others, i.e. $n-1$ people, as if they are seated linearly.

Comment: Then what is the number of events ?

Comment: If you could point out the exact video, I could be of more help. I only see the question in the image. Probability and combinatorics might have some sharp differences. But, if you're just asking for the how many ways these 5 people sit around the table conforming the conditions, that I can help directly.

Comment: There is no exact video. After 12 Unit 1 is over in that YouTube link question was asked. Not much helpful but that's all I can tell about it :(

Comment: OK. Did you understand "24 possible outcomes"?

Comment: I understand 24 is a combinatorics solution than a probability one. I understand how 5 people + 5 chairs lead to an ordered arrangement of 24. But how it applies to probability I don't understand. It is like saying we flip a coin 5 times then there are 5 outcomes. That's wrong number, outcomes are only 2, a H or T. But events (permutations) are 2^5 =  32. I don't know how to explain other than this